# How do I find the right software to upgrade ROM and flash for a Samsung J7 Sky Pro

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing

I need the software to upgrade my ROM and flash for a Samsung J7 Sky Pro. I don't really know what ROM is good and not too much. I flashed the phone once with Superuser, but it says that I didn't get something right. I just used an SD card. I don't have a desktop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need computer for this

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end-users. Looks like there are multiple questions here: 1) Software to upgrade/flash ROM for Samsung devices. 2) ROM recommendation. 3) Flashing Superuser. Note that ROM recommendation is off-topic since every ROM is different and has its own advantage. Regarding 1) and 3), did you try following some kinds of tutorial/guide? If so, could you mention it and also explain what you have done, so that other users can understand on which step do you need help?